# Query across two instances

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one Oracle Instance which homes a number of different Databases, I would like to query across all instances as some of the other database contain related information. How do I setup a query to connect to more that one instance as part of my SELECT statement..

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer if that helps.

Comment: [Database links](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm) and union statements.  `Select * from all_DB_LINKS;` for list of existing links you have access to.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Unless you're talking about a 12.1 instance with multiple pluggable databases, this question doesn't make a lot of sense (at least not if we use the Oracle definitions of "instance" and "database").  I'm guessing that you either have multiple schemas within a single database or you have multiple database instances.

Comment: running the above query returns 0 results, I will read the link supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Oracle 12.1 the relationship between Oracle Instances and Oracle Databases was 1 to 1.  A single instance could house at most 1 database, though a single server could host multiple instances.  However, a single database would have multiple schemas each of which could singly or cooperatively host 1 or more database applications.

Access from one Oracle Instance to another is possible via database links.  Database links may be either public or private and may be created with commands similar to this ([other options exist](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm)):

```
CREATE [PUBLIC] DATABASE LINK LINK_NAME
CONNECT TO SOME_SCHEMA
IDENTIFIED BY SOME_PASSWORD 
USING 'SOME_SERVICE_NAME';
```

Such a DB Link would be used to reference DB objects in the remote instance by appending the link name to the object reference with an at (`@`) sign, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM [SCHEMA.]TABLE_NAME@LINK_NAME;
```

The above select would return data provided the remote schema associated with the DB link (`SOME_SCHEMA` in the above create db link statement) has sufficient privileges to select from the referenced remote schema.

Comment: "the relationship between Oracle Instances and Oracle Databases was 1 to 1" Many to 1, with Oracle RAC.